# Using Enterprise core modules in Community Edition

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, magento-enterprise, magento-community

I have been working with Magento for quite a while now. This is not a question related to coding.

I was just wondering, if one copies a module from EE to CE, will it work?

For example, the customerbalance module used for store credit in EE. If I just extract the module files from EE and paste it into CE, will it work? At least, theoretically?

I am aware some modules may extend classes from other Enterprise modules. But if it doesn't will this work?

PS: I researched on Google, and surprisingly I couldn't find any post related to this.

Comment: You probably didn't find many because it is a license violation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is as you suspected, that some modules depend on each other, or worse, depend on the enterprise theme, so you would have to try it out. Magento is not known for being very honest with the `<depends>` declarations in core modules.

For some modules it will work without a problem, for others not so well. And you have to pay attention to also include all js, theme and skin files that belong to each module that you want to use.

Comment: Note that the answer is worded with specifics for Magento 1, but is just as valid for Magento 2 as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should work just like installing any other 3rd party module.

Keep in mind this might be illegal since the EE license does not allow you to do this without a valid license.